# SvelteKit - build component code only - without <head> etc

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

is there any way to let SvelteKit build only the code of one component.

E.g. lets say we have a component showing all participants of a conference. We would like to let SvelteKit generate only the

- HTML code of this table (without `<head>` and without other things within `<body>`)
- hydration-js for this specific table

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**No,** that is outside the scope of Svelte**Kit**.

It's achievable with Svelte (no Kit) by using [the Svelte compiler](https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time) with a custom setup.

To generate the html code you'll need to compile the components with `generate: 'ssr'`.
That will generate the javascript you can run on the server to generate the HTML.

The compiler output is unbundled and doesn't run in a browser without bundling.
To get the "hydration-js" you'll need to compile the components again but with `generate: 'dom', hydratable: true` using a [bundler](https://vite.dev/) with a [svelte plugin](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte).

Answer (score 1):

Rich Harris, the creator of Svelte(Kit), was [dogfooding Svelte(Kit) components on the NY Times site](https://svelte.dev/blog/sveltekit-beta), which is not a Svelte app. So I think it is possible.

I haven't tried it myself, but [Svelte Components as Web Components](https://www.colorglare.com/svelte-components-as-web-components-b400d1253504) describes how to convert SvelteKit components into web components.

Answer (score 1):

Using svelte components as web components is described in https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-custom-element-api